WPF - Customizing your ingame controls
I'm making a local multiplayer game in c# WPF. I'm struggling with customizeable user controls(key inputs). The game itself is a basic Bomberman. For 2 - 3 players. Ecach player can move up, down, left, right and place down a bomb. In the View layer I made a ControlSettingPage. I also set its DataContext to my ViewModel instance, so the bindings should work properly.
Here is the View:
<Page x:Class="Bomberman.View.ControlSettingsPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Bomberman.View"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      Title="Control Settings">

        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <StackPanel Margin="10">
                <!-- Player 1 Controls -->
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <StackPanel Margin="10">
                    <TextBlock Text="Player 1 Controls" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Up Key:" />
                            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Player1Controls.UpKey, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Down Key:" />
                            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Player1Controls.DownKey, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Left Key:" />
                            <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Player1Controls.LeftKey, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Right Key:" />
                            <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Player1Controls.RightKey, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="Bomb Key:" />
                            <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Player1Controls.BombKey, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
            </Border>

            <!-- Player 2 Controls -->
            <!-- Similar to player 1 -->

            <!-- Player 2 Controls -->
            <!-- Similar to player 1 -->

            <!-- Save Button -->
            <Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding SaveControlSettingsCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,20" />

            <Button Content="Back to Main Menu" Click="BackToMain_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,20"/>
    </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Page>


This is the relevent part of the ViewModel:
// Player control properties
public DelegateCommand SaveControlSettingsCommand { get; private set; }
public PlayerControl Player1Controls { get; set; }
public PlayerControl Player2Controls {  get; set; }
public PlayerControl Player3Controls { get; set; }

//In constructor
SaveControlSettingsCommand = new DelegateCommand(param => onSaveControlSettings());
//Control settings (also in constructor)
Player1Controls = _model.Player1Controls;
Player2Controls = _model.Player2Controls;
Player3Controls = _model.Player3Controls;

//Event method
private void onSaveControlSettings()
{
    _model.SaveControlSettings(Player1Controls,Player2Controls,Player3Controls);
}

When I run my game and navigate to the Control Settings menu I get the 3 (players) * 5 (controls) long list where the textboxes are filled with the default(starter) values, control setting. But every time I try to change a value there, my new value instantly reverts back to the original. Everytime I get the Textbox out of focus it switches back.
Am I doing something wrong in the code that I provided? If not where is my problem coming from? I'm not dealing with control settings anywhere else. There is only a save method for it in the _model. But that should not override my PlayerXControls in the VM.
Since I'm using TwoWay binding my first idea was to check if something in the VM changes the PlayerControls but I didn't find anything.
Please help! Thank you!

I guess there would be something wrong in your PlayerControl or bindings with it.

Based on the information provided we can only guess what went wrong, since it is clearly not in the code you have provided. What I can suggest is to debug getter setter and look from the stack where assignment is coming from and share the PlayerControl VM (since it seems the issue might be there).
